# Recommended Multithreading / parallel computing books for C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to start reading about multithreading and parallel computing in C# / .Net 4.0.

I understand the basics of multithreading so I'm looking for something that is going to provide more than just the basics. I'm also looking for something that is up to date with the  changes in .Net 4.0.

Can you recommend a book?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose when it comes to anything in C#, I would recommend [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632). It has got two chapters on threading-parallelprocessing which is a must read.

Comment: +1 An oldie, but a goodie. :)

Comment: That's a great recommendation. Another, not as hard-core but still very good is Professional C# 4 and .NET 4 published by Wrox. Just one dedicated chapter on threading etc., a good step up from just the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I've going to get CLR via C#. Not only for the threading content but there's a lot in this book that I should be reading. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4, which cover different senarios and implementation:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [this chapter](http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf) from [C# in nutshell 4.0](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), It's really a greate resource.

Good luck!

Comment: This looks like a great resource. I will be using this for sure - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm making my way through http://www.albahari.com/threading/ which I find to be a very useful resource.  It's been updated to cover the new parallel options in c# 4.0.

Comment: Yes, that's a great resource. I came back to post that link, but you beat me to it. If you really want just a (free) book on threads etc. (and no other C# stuff), this is it - not that other books that contain info about threading/parallel aren't worth it. Threads only, very heady.

Answer (score 2):

[Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) by Joe Duffy.  It has everything you need to know about concurrency multi-threading including PLINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good start: [Parallel Computing Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx)

[A Tour Through the Parallel Programming Samples for .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/12/09/9934811.aspx)